# Recommendation On Data Store For Website's User Activity Log

Tags: performance, web, feed, datastore

I am looking for some recommendations on a good data store for activity feeds. The goal is to have a Twitter/Facebook type feed log consisting of various activities users can do throughout our website. The "wall" or "feed" would updated via AJAX showing what the users of the website are currently doing. It will be written to often and then the most recent will be displayed on the site.
(e.g. John Smith recommended Jane Smith's article 2 seconds ago)

We currently are storing the feeds in MySQL but performance has been poor and I'm concerned with hindering performance throughout the rest of the website if we are constantly hitting the database to grab the most recent user activity as well as writing the feeds.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the best caching solutions like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) to increase performance. Other than scaling, there are no performance-increasing possibilities for an activity feed.

I would vote for using http://redis.io/ or http://www.mongodb.org/ as an alternative to MySQL for short-term, almost live activity feeds across a site. And a cron job to dump history of activities into MySQL for record keeping.

A look at [tumblr's](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/2/13/tumblr-architecture-15-billion-page-views-a-month-and-harder.html) or [twitters](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster) architectures can push you to the right direction as well.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I'll review your suggestions straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the microservices approach to separate between the datastore that stores the users' actions to the one that store the actual data. 
[Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) is the right approach to handle the big stream of users' actions. 
Use Kafka or Google Pub/Sub cloud service for a scalable data pipeline. They can take the load with its scalable architecture. 
Independently consume the messages from Kafka to some database such as MySQL or Google BigQuery for analytics purposes you must have.